# Problems in settings with PHP Storm and PHP-FPM, trying to setup XDebug to work properly

Tags: php, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

There are several problems:

First: I have my local server with NGinx and PHP-FPM installed. I have also added the xdebug to PHP. But PHP Storm can't recognize the /usr/sbin/php5-fpm. It accepts only usual PHP - /usr/bin/php5. I've tried to add XDebug config to that version, but it haven't worked properly (both - cli and cgi version). With usual PHP it works, but I'm using different version, and I want to setup it properly to version of php-fpm and not cli or cgi. Please tell me how to do this!

Second: when I'm running a debug, putting the break points, it runs with address - localhost:9000?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=12662. It work only if I clean the port number. But it can't run without port. And if I try another project (produced with framework for example), not few simple php files, it doesn't propose me an address at all! When I hit the button "run" or "debug" it opens a new blank inset. I guess it is setup problem, but help me to solve this! Thank you!

Comment: 1) Screenshots please. So far it looks like you have screw up the project and maybe even an IDE settings (over-configured or even configured wrong things). 2) What are you trying to debug -- a web page or CLI script?

Comment: 1) Usual: [link](http://i.imgur.com/HNjjFGc.png)
With PHP-FPM: [link](http://i.imgur.com/cqmGJf5.png)

2) I'm trying to debug difficult logic, so it's not always usual pages, it could be as script with several sub calls to other scripts, or some output into a page sometimes. So I guess it is mixed. But I'm not use my code as a console application, if you mean that.

Comment: 1) Since you are not going to debug CLI (console app) then there is no need to setup PHP Interpreter. Your PHP processing will be handled by nginx -- PhpStorm will not call it directly. If you only need to setup PHP Interpreter (normal CLI version: just `php`) if you want to use other CLI tools that PhpStorm has integration with (like PHPUnit, Phing, PHPCS etc)

Comment: 2) How do you run your page that you have got `localhost:9000` in it. In general this is wrong. TCP 9000 is used by xdebug (by default) for communicating with debug client (PhpStorm in our case) -- it should NOT be the port in URL. This means that you have edited the wrong "port" settings. try to find it.